# GCM push notification is not showing in some devices when app is not running

Tags: android, push-notification

I am implement GCM Push Notification in my app and its successfully done but in some devices it not show notification when app is close.

List of device which notication is not show:

Redmi-2

lenovo

Gionee

Can anyone explain me what is problem and how i solve its.

here my manifest:-

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="student.skoolstar.android.catalyst.com.schoolstar.skoolstarstudent">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

  <permission
   android:name="student.skoolstar.android.catalyst.com.schoolstar.skoolstarstudent.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
   android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="student.skoolstar.android.catalyst.com.schoolstar.skoolstarstudent.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

  <application
   android:name="student.skoolstar.android.catalyst.com.schoolstar.skoolstarstudent.Controller"
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".Login"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".ListOfClass"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".EditProfile"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".ShowStudentList"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
   <receiver
    android:name="student.skoolstar.android.catalyst.com.schoolstar.skoolstarstudent.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

     <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
     <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

     <category android:name="schoolstar.com.catalyst.android.skoolstar" />
    </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

   <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
   <activity
    android:name=".Message"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".Attendance"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>

   <activity
    android:name=".NewMessage"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".GroupMessage"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
   <activity
    android:name=".Test_Chat"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
   </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

here my service name GCMNotificationIntentService:-

```
    public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Database db;

    private Controller aController = null;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        // Call extended class Constructor GCMBaseIntentService
        super(Constants.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

    }
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.d("unref",registrationId);
        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
                getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        aController.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {

        Log.d("error","");

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,

                getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        String formuser = intent.getExtras().getString("formuser");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
        Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
        String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);


        db = new Database(context);
        int  from_id = 0;

        List<FetchData> fetchdata = db.getAllContacts();
        for (FetchData fd : fetchdata)
        {

            from_id=fd.getID();//get ser no
        }

        db.storeMessage(420, formuser, from_id + "", message, "text", localTime, "F", "ST", "R");

        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        // notifies user
        sendNotification(context,message);
    }

    private void sendNotification(Context context,String msg) {
        String app_name = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ListOfClass.class), 0);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(app_name)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText("New Message")
                .setSound(alarmSound);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);
        //  Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

When I am see the whatsapp, hike and others notification app he will always run in background thread but my app is not running always in background. So may be this reason be also.
I am recently working on android please help me.Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try new implementation of gcm which uses WakefulBroadcastReceiver in which we start a intent service?

Comment: Have you try to use Instance ID api for GCM registration?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with Redmi-2. There is no problem in the code but it is due to Custom UI provided by the Manufacturer like MIUI 6.
So to enable GCM notifications

Go to Security App >> Tap on permissions >> Tap on Auto Start and enable auto start for your App.

Comment: Can I do by this programmatically like whatsapp,hike and others app ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two major reasons for that

1 - Some devices does not allow you to run a service on background like redmi-2 ( almost on all xiaomi device ). Even whats app could not work properly on them unless user allow them by going to Security App >> Tap on permissions >> Tap on Auto Start and enable auto start for whatsapp etc. In this case all you can do is to show the details of this to user on application start up. And open that screen and guide user ( if possible ) like clean master.

2- Second reason is that it didn't work on one of those phone whose Google Play Services app wasn't installed correctly(and its essential for GCM). You can not do anything on these devices also. The only thing you can do in this case is just show some message to user about this.

So from my experience there always be a number of users(but very small percentage) who wont receive GCM push.

Comment: How to find in which phone need to do auto-start code? Means I know In **MI device** it is required for auto-start But don't know about others .

Answer (score 1):

There is concept of whitelisting in Xiaomi's phone. So, if you put log in  onReceive of gcm, you will notice that gcm is receiving but it's not processing further. Its cause your app is not whitelisted.

Xiaomi for security purposes disables the Notification for each Application. Follow these steps to receive messages in background once they quit the app using cleaner.

- Enable Autostart
- Enable Floating and Lock Screen Notification

### Enable AutoStart

- Open Security App.
- Got to Permissions, then Click on Auto Start Management.
- Add/Enable auto start apps (e.g. Whatsapp).

### Enable Floating and Lock Screen Notification

- Open Settings App.
- Click on Notifications, then click on Manage Notifications.
- Tap on the App which you are looking for (e.g. WhatsApp).
- Enable Show in notification shade / Show on lockscreen and in drop down option.

For Reference check this out : http://support.hike.in/entries/55998480-I-m-not-getting-notification-on-my-Xiaomi-Phone-For-MIUI-6-

i got success with this.. Hope it helps..

Comment: How to find in which phone need to do auto-start code? Means I know In **MI device** it is required for auto-start But don't know about others .

Comment: @bdevloper do you get to know which device has an auto - start option as this option is not available in some stock android devices?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, the only things we did are to educate xiaomi users to do the steps as @anup-dasari mentioned, and set the gcm priority to high, with possibility to have persistent service in the future