# How to enable autostart option in device security?

Tags: android, security, background, google-cloud-messaging, autostart

I have next issue: when we kill the process - application dos not receive any message from GCM.

Some android devices have own "security" manager. If we turn on option "autostart" in it - all work great. Application receive all successful.

Have someone any idea how to turn on this without user configure actions?

Comment: I think this is impossible, because those "security managers" doesn't have any api. BTW, I have never seen something like this

Comment: @DimaRostopira find xiaomi or asus and check it)

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402305/gcm-push-notification-is-not-showing-in-some-devices-when-app-is-not-running/35402398) if it can help you.